# Magento 2: How to check the current page is home in phtml?

Tags: magento2, template

Magento version: 2.0.0

How to check the current page is home page in the template file? 
There has a global function to do it?

Answer (score 8):

Set block content with custom function :

```
protected $_request;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_request = $request;
    ...
}

public function isHomepage()
{

    if ($this->_request->getFullActionName() == 'cms_index_index') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Template code :

```
<?php  $isHome = $block->isHomepage(); ?>
```

Comment: You can also use "$this->getRequest()->getFullActionName()" in blocks using class "Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
$currentUrl = $this->getUrl('', ['_current' => true]);
$urlRewrite = $this->getUrl('*/*/*', ['_current' => true, '_use_rewrite' => true]);
$isHome = $currentUrl == $urlRewrite;
```

In addition you can use the `\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo::isHomePage()` method if you has this block in all pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check

```
$objectManagerCms = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cmsPage = $objectManagerCms->get('\Magento\Cms\Model\Page');

echo $cmsPage->getIdentifier(); //Current CMS Page Identifier
```

Comment: It's bad practice to use Object Manager. Especially when the needed information can be found in Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http as mentioned by @ronak-chauhan.